# Affects of nicotine on the nerves

Tags: neurology, nerves, neuropathy, nicotine, neurodegenerative-disease

There are new methods for getting nicotine. For example, vaping. Some people are almost promoting nicotine as a health product that can reduce the risk of Parkison's disease and colitis. Some people are even starting to use nicotine as a nootropic.

What long term affect does Nicotine consumption have on the nervous system? Generally speaking, could it cause neuropathy or perhaps make it better?

**Note:** I am NOT asking about smoking tobacco or cigarettes, which have many other chemicals. I just want to know about Nicotine by itself.